how to fix dummy output amd soundcard huawei matebook d15 ubuntu 22.04?
Hello I've been trying to fix the dummy output in my ubuntu 22.04 for a long time. I've tried everything on the internet and nothing helped(sometimes I got a second dummy output but when I switched to it settings app just crashed and after that there was only 1 dummy  output as before). I also tried this: https://github.com/Smoren/huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix but it didn't help either. The system also can't detect my microphone so I have no input devices. Wired headphones don't work either. I can't even connect my bluetooth headphones. I can connect 'em for about 10 seconds(and then they disconnect). As always there's no sound in the bluetooth headphones when they are connected and I can't see 'em in the output devices either. This is my inxi -F output
System:
  Host: andrey-BOM-WXX9 Kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.9 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HUAWEI product: BOM-WXX9 v: M1010
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HUAWEI model: BOM-WXX9-PCB-B2 v: M1010 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: HUAWEI v: 2.12 date: 03/16/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 19.4 Wh (35.5%) condition: 54.6/54.9 Wh (99.3%)
    volts: 7.4 min: 7.6
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP cache: L2: 3 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 483 min/max: 400/4056 cores: 1: 400 2: 400 3: 400
    4: 400 5: 400 6: 400 7: 1398 8: 400 9: 400 10: 400 11: 400 12: 400
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Lucienne driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-2: IMC Networks ov9734_azurewave_camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: RENOIR (renoir LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.54 6.5.0-28-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-28-generic running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    driver: rtw_8822ce
  IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: 84:c8:a0:50:ff:86
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: 84:C8:A0:50:FF:87 bt-v: 3.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 10.41 GiB (2.2%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: PCIe-8 SSD 512GB size: 476.94 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 118.65 GiB used: 10.38 GiB (8.7%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 32.8 MiB (34.1%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 36.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 34.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 329 Uptime: 4m Memory: 14.95 GiB used: 1.87 GiB (12.5%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13

also my apply -l:
** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

When I try alsamixer I can't do anything either.
Switching to ubuntu 23.10 doesn't help either so I was curious.
Is there any way to fix my problem or is my laptop not for linux cuz of its soundcard? should I just give up and use windows again instead?
